# Homomorphisms of abelian varieties constitute a finitely generated abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups, abelian-varieties, free-abelian-group

Let $X, Y$ be abelian varieties over $k$. Let $l$ be a prime not equal to the characteristic of $k$. Then one shows that $\text{Hom}_k(X, Y)\to \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_l}(T_l X, T_l Y)$ is injective. Moreover, it is shown that the $\mathbb{Z}_l$ linear map $\text{Hom}_k(X, Y)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_l \to \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_l}(T_l X, T_l Y), f\otimes c\mapsto c\cdot T_l(f)$ is injective with torsion-free cokernel and that $T_l X$ and $T_l Y$ are non-canonically isomorphic to free $\mathbb{Z}_l$ modules of finite rank.

Then it is concluded that $\text{Hom}_k(X,Y)$ is a free abelian group of finite rank. I can not understand how that can be concluded from the above. (See for example Ben Moonen's draft for a book on abelian varieties chapter 15).

At first, this seemed rather obvious but check out the second answer to the question [Checking that a torsion-free abelian group has finite rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901563/checking-that-a-torsion-free-abelian-group-has-finite-rank) here on math-exchange.

Comment: You could vary the prime $\ell$, but I guess that still does not rule out the possibility $\hom_k(X,Y)=\mathbb Z[1/p]$ where $char(k)=p$.

Comment: Yes, varying $l$ doesn't work by the linked question and the second answer there

Comment: @FabioNeugebauer: *"Then it is concluded that [...]"* - maybe tell us where it is concluded that [...]?

Comment: @Alex M. Its concluded in Ben Moonens book on Abelian Varieties or in Milne's 1986 text on Abelian Varieties in theorem 12.5

Answer (score 0):

Mb, I rushed through the problem and accidentally made a mistake, that your third problem highlighted. Revised answer below:

The statement that HomZl(TlX,TlY) is a free abelian group of finite rank was incorrect. Instead, HomZl(TlX,TlY) is a free Zl-module of finite rank.

Despite this, the conclusion that Homk(X,Y) is a free abelian group of finite rank still holds. This is because of the following reasons:

The homomorphism Homk(X,Y) → HomZl(TlX,TlY) being injective implies that the image of Homk(X,Y) in HomZl(TlX,TlY) is a subgroup of finite index.

The Zl-linear map Homk(X,Y) ⊗ Zl → HomZl(TlX,TlY), f ⊗ c → c ⋅ Tl(f) being injective with torsion-free cokernel implies that Homk(X,Y) is a direct summand of HomZl(TlX,TlY), which is a free Zl-module of finite rank.

As a direct summand of a free Zl-module of finite rank, Homk(X,Y) must also have finite rank as a abelian group.

Therefore, we can conclude that Homk(X,Y) is a free abelian group of finite rank.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I do not understand the following: For the first fact, why has it finite index. For the second fact, I think I see that $\text{Hom}_k(X,  Y)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_l$ will be a direct summand of a free $\mathbb{Z_l}$ module of finite rank, how does the rest follow? Also, I don't get why $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_l}(T_l X, T_l Y)$ should have finite rank as abelian group, I think it has finite rank as $\mathbb{Z}_l$ module, but $\mathbb{Z}_l$ has infinite rank as abelian group?

Comment: I see that $\text{Hom}_k(X,Y)$ must have finite rank as torsion free abelian group. But e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies the same and is far from being free.